# How can I stop gnu parallel jobs when any one of them terminates?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Suppose I am running N jobs with the following gnu parallel command:

```
seq $N | parallel -j 0 --progress ./job.sh
```

How can I invoke parallel to kill all running jobs and accept no more as soon as any one of them exits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `--halt`:

```
seq $N | parallel -j 0 --halt now,done=1 ./job.sh
```

Comment: In newer versions of GNU Parallel you can use '--halt now,success=1' It will exit when a job succeeds and kill running jobs.

Comment: Modern syntax for `--halt 2` is `--halt now,fail=1`

Answer (score -1):

You may also use `killall perl`. It's not accurate way, but easy to remember